# Google Calendar API - Public calendar not found 404 Error

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api

My Android Application  reads shared calendar (public calendar). It worked six months without problems.

From two week, users (guest) receive 404 Not Found Error.
Owner's calendar use the app without any problems.

So i think that property of sharing are changed. Any ideas?

Also, how can get more info about 404 - Not found error?

App is this --> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=airbookingapp.hairbooking

It's only in italian but if you selct "Only for debug" salon you can get the error!

Comment: Which android OS you are testing

Comment: I'm testing API 24. Write also here but without responce [here](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/msgid/calendar/e142a150-5cc0-451b-96c0-7b9d8e6d5fe2%40googleproductforums.com.)

Comment: test it below 23.. I mean just try to test it on 22 or any other below version of android

Comment: Changed targetSdkVersion from 24 to 23 but nothing....

Answer (score 0):

Try using this [workaround](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/A3MPcv3aBcs) by unsubscribing to the calendar function then subscribed again after a day (via Organization & Users). Also based from this [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors#404_not_found), this error means that the specified resource was not found. This can happen in several cases such as: *when the requested resource (with the provided ID) has never existed* and *when accessing a calendar that the user can not access*. Suggested action is to use [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors#exponential-backoff).

Comment: Suggest workaround is for Google App for Business... I'm a simple Google User that shared your google calendar! My calendar is public.. look here https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=hairbookingapp%40gmail.com&ctz=Europe/Rome

Comment: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Not Found",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "Not Found"
}

Comment: So, after more test, I notice that usual "consent screen" for new user does not appear.. Consent screen is typical for app that use google api service... more more strange!